# Calling functions inside JavaScript 'for' loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call multiple functions in a JavaScript 'for' loop, but they are only being called the first time and the loops terminates.

I have tried making the functions unique, by passing a value to them, using some generic function caller such as:

```
for(i=0; i<50; i++){
    alert('test');
    generator_function(i);
}


function generator_function(variable){
   function1(variable);
   function2(variable);
   function3(variable);
   function4(variable);
   var sum = local_array.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b });
   var avg = sum / local_array.length;
}
```

Which seems to work, but the local arrays still hold the elements from the first loop.

Is there a better way of calling a collection of functions inside a loop? I have global arrays which are being altered in these loops and am wondering if they need to be local, i.e. inside the functions somehow?

Comment: one possible problem is `for(i=0; i<50; i++){` here `i` is a global variable if inside any one of the function(where i is again in global scope) `i`s value is changed to > 50 then the loop will get terminated. Try `for( var i=0; i<50; i++){` instead

Comment: To be sure: You can see only one alert? If so, there might be an error occured when executing one of the functions in `generator_function`. Have you checked the console, there should be an error message.

Comment: The functions work fine on their own. I think @Arun may be right in talking about the local variable in the loops. I had a lot of those and wondered why you needed the 'var'. I will run a few tests but feel free to put that as an answer.

Comment: @Jon posting as an answer

Comment: @Jon Well, now you know, why to use `var` : ).

Comment: Where is `local_array` defined at all? How do the functions interact with it?

Comment: Sorry that was mis-leading. local_array is defined at the top of the script. I don't think that is an issue, because it is working in other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible problem is `for(i=0; i<50; i++){` here i is a global variable if inside any one of the function(where `i` is again in global scope) is value is changed to > 50 then the loop will get terminated they both references the same instance in the global scope. Try `for( var i=0; i<50; i++){` instead.

When you use `var` in a variable declaration, that variable will be created in the local scope(the function in which it is declared)